# Determine When Windows Computer has fully booted and becomes responsive

Tags: c#, windows, boot

I know this question has been asked before in different situations.

I want to write a C# program that pops up a message when a Windows Vista or Windows 7 computer has fully booted up.  (Everything is loaded, the hard drive has settled and the computer is responsive)

Currently I am using a timer.  I was wondering if there was maybe a way to determine when all the services have started or something like that?

Edit:

I have something that seems to work fairly well:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    private PerformanceCounter diskCounter;
    private int seconds;
    private int lowUsage;

    private const String timeMsg = "Waiting for Boot: ";
    private const String cpuMsg = "CPU: ";
    private const String diskMsg = "Disk: ";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        diskCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        diskCounter.CategoryName = "PhysicalDisk";
        diskCounter.CounterName = "% Disk Time";
        diskCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        seconds = 0;
        lowUsage = 0;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += tick;
        timer.Start();

        timeLabel.Text = timeMsg + seconds;
        cpuLabel.Text = cpuMsg + "100%";
        diskLabel.Text = diskMsg + "100%";

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

    }

    private void tick(Object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        seconds++;
        int cpu = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
        int disk = (int)diskCounter.NextValue();

        if (cpu < 5 && disk < 5) lowUsage++;
        else lowUsage = 0;

        if (lowUsage >= 5 && seconds > 35) Application.Exit();

        timeLabel.Text = timeMsg + seconds;
        cpuLabel.Text = cpuMsg + cpu + "%";
        diskLabel.Text = diskMsg + disk + "%"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly that straight-forward.  Use PerformanceCounter, observe the Memory + Page Faults/sec counter.  Don't declare happiness too early.

Comment: There are some parts of the system that wait 30 seconds after boot is complete to start initializing, so waiting for CPU and I/O to drop is not proof that the system has fully initialized. And there are some parts of the system that *never* initialize until they are first used. If you wanted to wait for those, you will be waiting indefinitely. What are you trying to measure? (What do you intend to use this information for?)

Comment: I support computers for people who do not know much about computers - They are always frustrated that things do not seem to work when they start up.  I am creating this program to approximate a good time to start using the computer.  I know that this routine needs to be tuned for each particular computer.  I tried a timer - some computers need 4 minutes to boot some need only 30 seconds.  I was looking for a different approach.  I have had good luck with the 3 computers I have installed this on so far with no modifications.  If you can think of anything better, please give some suggestions.

Comment: I added a minimum wait time of 35 seconds from when the program starts - this seems to work well for Windows XP - Thank you Raymond for your comment.  I simply put a short-cut to this program in Startup folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try for resting CPU usage, hard drive usage, or perhaps a combination of both. My computer is 1 to 4% usage if nothing is going on. During boot it's much higher. Might have to do some kind of math to find trends of spikes and stability. That's how I'd go about it, anyway. I don't know about the services option. I kinda doubt there's a way to ask each one if they're done loading and doing their thing even if you could get a list of them.

Comment: Excellent idea - I just wrote a program to sampling cpu usage every second.  When three successive zeros happen booting is done.  How do I test hard drive usage?

Comment: You can access them using WMI (windows management instrumentation) from cpu, hdd, network, memory, so on...

Comment: Can I use PerformaceCounter to test Hard Drive Usage?  If so how?

Comment: Of course this is not fool proof. When my Bitcoin wallet application is started by Windows right after boot, and it starts to download the latest updates to the block chain, my computer gets unbearably slow. Even though Windows has started properly, your application won't detect it.

Comment: I know this is an approximation.  I am not 100% satisfied.  But if I can get people to stop complaining (some of the computers I support) It is worth it.  Also, I don't have to re-write different timer values for different computers.  Most of the people's computers I support have a hard enough time opening a Browser.